# Typescript - how to pass MyClass.new as method reference?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects, where each object looks like this:

```js
{ id: 'string', name: 'string' }
```

Given this class:

```js
class User {
  constructor(obj: Record<string, string>) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }

  id: string; 
  name: string;
}
```

I want to use `Array.map()` to create an array of `User`:

```js
const users = userObjects.map(o => new User(o));
```

The above works, but feels wrong: is there a way to pass a reference to the `User`'s `new` and avoid the arrow function?

I'm not really sure if the answer is different between Javascript and Typescript (I suspect it isn't), but FWIW I'm coding in Typescript.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't (other than a utility function you might write to do that arrow function for you, but that's just an abstraction on what you already have). The issue is that there *is* no `new` method (like Java's `User::new`), there is only the `User` function itself, and whether it creates a `User` instance or throws an error (in modern environments) depends on how you call it. If you call it via `new` (or a similar mechanism like `Reflect.construct`), it creates a `User` instance. If you call it directly, it throws an error (in ES2015+; if you're compiling down to ES5, it won't, but it won't work properly either).

What you have (the wrapper arrow function) is a perfectly good way to do it (and probably what I'd do).

If you need to do this in several places, you could put a static method on `User`:

```
class User {
    // ...
    static create(...args) {
        return new User(...args);
    }
}
// ...
const users = userObjects.map(User.create);
```

(Note that `create` won't work properly in `User` subclasses [depending on your definition of "properly"], it always creates a `User` instance, even if called as `UserSubclass.create(/*...*/)`. Normally you could use `this` instead of `User` [`new this(...args)`], which while it looks odd works provided the call sets `this` correctly [as `User.create(/*...*/)` or `UserSubclass.create(/*...*/)` would], but `map` won't set `this` correctly so that wouldn't work unless you `bind` `create` or remember to pass the second argument to `map` [`.map(User.create, User)`], which takes us back to: a wrapper arrow function probably makes more sense.)

Comment: *Originally I had the caveat "well, not reasonably" on my "No, there isn't." But the unreasonable way I was thinking of doesn't work. (FWIW: I was thinking you could `bind` `User` to [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) (`map(Reflect.construct.bind(Reflect, User))`), but that doesn't work: `Reflect.construct` expects the arguments for the target function as a single array, and `map` would just pass the object to it directly, not wrapped in an array. It would be a bad idea even if it worked, IMHO. :-)*

Comment: You can make it work with a helper `unary` function. But I'd agree it's not exactly reasonable.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, I added a caveat about that a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for something like Java's `User::new` -- especially since Typescript looks a lot like Java.

Comment: @noamtm - Yeah. Although the aspects of TypeScript that look like Java are mostly JavaSript, which looks like Java for historic marketing reasons (Java was big in the mid-90s, and Netscape wanted their new, unrelated language to get lots of adoption). (Although amusingly, one aspect of the similarity between Java and JavaScript goes the other way: Java added a `var` keyword almost 20 years after JavaScript's.) The TypeScript parts aren't very Java-like: `let a: int;` (TS) vs. `int a;` (Java), `let x = y as SubType;` (TS) vs. `SubType x = (SubType)y;` or `var x = (SubType)y;` (Java), ...  :-)

Comment: Actually my comment referred to newer (non-JS) things like `extends`, `implements`, and `XYZ[]`.

Comment: @noamtm - `extends` is JavaScript too. :-) But fair enough on `implements` (it was the obvious choice) and array notation. TypeScript also lets you use `Array<XYZ>` if you like. So like JavaScript, it's a superficial syntax relationship, there's no deep relationship. TypeScript's type system is structural, for instance, whereas Java's is nominal. Happy coding!